# AlarmMananger Not working

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-intent, time

Even after setting the time correctly, the Log.i never gets called. It worked until I created a array of intents to go with the array of PendingIntents.

This is my main activity

```
public void actionSetup(boolean activitycreated[],int buttonclicked[])
    {
        SharedPreferences data=getSharedPreferences("ACTIVITY_DATA",MODE_MULTI_PROCESS);
        Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
        myintent[buttonclicked[0]]=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),actionservice.class);
        myintent[buttonclicked[0]].putExtra("activityfrom",buttonclicked[0]);
        stuff[buttonclicked[0]]=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this,buttonclicked[0],myintent[buttonclicked[0]],PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

              calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH,Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH));
              calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR,Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR));
              calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
              calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, data.getInt(buttonclicked[0]+"startimehour",1));
              calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, data.getInt(buttonclicked[0]+"startimeminute",1));
              calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);
              if (data.getInt(buttonclicked[0]+"startimehour",1)>=12)
              {
                  calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM,Calendar.PM);
              }
              else
              {
                  calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM,Calendar.AM);
              }

              AlarmManager alarmManager= (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
              alarmManager.set(alarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.getTimeInMillis(),stuff[buttonclicked[0]]);
            }
        }
```

This is my service.

```
   public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{


    Bundle extras= intent.getExtras();

    int originact=extras.getInt("activityfrom");

    Log.i("ORIGIN OF THIS ACT!!!!!!","ADJKLJWEIRJWEIRWER"); SOMEHOW THIS NEVER GETS LOGGED!!!!!!

    SharedPreferences data=getSharedPreferences("ACTIVITY_DATA",MODE_MULTI_PROCESS);

    boolean daysselected [] []=new boolean[8][7];

    boolean [] [] functionsselected=new boolean[8][2];

    for(int m=0;m<=7;m++)
    {
            functionsselected[m][0]=data.getBoolean("silent"+m,false);
            functionsselected[m][1]=data.getBoolean("bluetooth"+m,false);
    }

    for(int i=0;i<=7;i++)
    {
      for(int j=0;j<=6;j++)
      {
          daysselected[i][j]=data.getBoolean("activity"+i+"day"+j,false);
      }
    }

    Calendar c= Calendar.getInstance();
    int dayofweek=c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);





    Handler.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
    stopSelf();

    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it, I had set the extras for the intent but forgot to set the intent itself -_-